# how to fix the error on the Round, what should i change the line to?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public void ChangeTexts(long length, int position, int percent, double speed)
        {
            Label3.Text = "File Size: " + Math.Round((length / 1024), 2) + " KB";
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Math.Round(double, int)' and 'Math.Round(decimal, int)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently dividing by 1024 *in integer arithmetic* and then rounding the result. In other words, you're rounding something that's already an integer - not really useful.

The simplest fix is to divide by 1024.0 instead, to make it happen in `double` arithmetic:

```
Label3.Text = "File Size: " + Math.Round((length / 1024.0), 2) + " KB";
```

Or better, just do it within the formatting itself:

```
Label3.Text = $"File Size: {length / 1024.0:0.00}KB";
```

Answer (score 2):

Error is self explanary. You should specify what type you want to use. It happends becouse `Math.Round()` method doesn't have overload for `long`.

So you can do it like this:

```
 public void ChangeTexts(long length, int position, int percent, double speed)
 {
     Label3.Text = "File Size: " + Math.Round((length / 1024d), 2) + " KB";
 }
```

Now you operate with `double` type. `d` is a [literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691085(v=vs.71).aspx) for `double` type. Now expression `(double)length / 1024d` will return `double`. And `Math.Round` has overload for it.

Comment: That's now going to perform the division in integer arithmetic, cast that integer to a decimal, and round it to 2 decimal places. How is that useful?

Comment: That still won't compile due to the semi-colon, and you don't need *both* operands to be `double`. As I say in my answer, I think it's simpler just to get the formatting to do it, to be honest...